# How to make a script which outputs the ratio of the factorials of two numbers (N! / M!)?

Tags: php, math

I have a code that find n factorial:

```
    $n = 5;
    $factorial = 1;

    function fact($n)
   { 
       for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
           $factorial *= $i;
       }
   }
   echo $factorial;
```

but, how can I find the ratio of the factorials of two numbers `(N! / M!)`?

Comment: Here's where I would start: `function twoFactorial($n, $m) {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a return in you function and call her 2 times:

```
$n = 5;
$m = 2;

function fact(Int $n) : Int{ 
   $factorial = 1;
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
       $factorial *= $i;
   }
   return $factorial;
}

$factorialOfTwoNumbers = fact($n) / fact($m);
```

Answer (score 3):

Uhh, that's potentially a *lot* of unnecessary math you're doing there with @Kyoto's answer.

```php
// return N!/M!
function factorial_ratio($n, $m) {
    if( $n == $m ) {
        return 1;
    } else if( $n > $m ) {
        return partial_factorial($n, $m+1);
    } else {
        return 1 / partial_factorial($m, $n+1);
    }
}

function partial_factorial($begin, $end) {
    if( ! $begin >  $end ) {
        throw new \Exception("Begin must be larger than end");
    }
    $out = $begin;
    for( $f=$begin-1; $f>=$end; --$f ) {
        $out *= $f;
    }
    return $out;
}

var_dump(factorial_ratio(123456789, 123456788));
```

Output: [in 20ms]

```
int(123456789)
```

Eg:

```
( 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 ) / ( 1 * 2 * 3 ) == ( 4 * 5 )
```